# Make it easy to give cells names based on a value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to name Cells based on values in another cell. I've tried to record a macro to do this but just does not work out. I've got a way to get the cells and needed names into an array like this (note that there MANY more field than shown below, I have several worksheets to do this on, and all the field names are not the same as below):

....B...........................................C..............................................D

Field Label .................Cell Address...............................New Cell Name

First Name...........................I3.......................................FirstName

Last Name...........................L3.......................................LastName

Address 1.............................I5.......................................Address1

Address 2.............................I6.......................................Address2

City.......................................I7.......................................City

State.....................................I8.......................................State

When I try to record a macro (and I've tried it several different ways), where I select and copy the desired cell name and paste it into the name Box in excel, I get the code below. It does not work in the end, plus it gets specific with the cell names. I need it to be general so I can apply it to any array in any worksheet.

```
Sub nameFields()
    '
    ' nameFields Macro
    '
        Selection.copy
        Range("I3").Select
        Application.Goto Reference:="FirstName"
        Range("D3").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.copy
        Range("L3").Select
        Application.Goto Reference:="LastName"
        Range("D4").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.copy
        Range("I5").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Address1", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R5C9"
    End Sub
```

(I have also looked for a way to do it right in excel, with something like naming the first cell in the array and then dragging down to cell to auto fill in the named ranges (like Field1, Field2, etc), but there does not seem to a way to do that either).

Any suggestions? Obviously, I am not a VBA wizzard. I'd go ahead and just trudge through it manually, but there are lots of fields and lots of workbooks. Plus, I'm thinking I can combine an answer from this into a side project about making an easily customizable entry form in excel. anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [Create Names from Cell Text](https://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) and check if this meets your needs. Excel has already a feature called *"Create (Names) from Selection"* in the *"Formulas"* ribbon. You can use that to create names of multiple cells at once by the value in their neighbour cells. No need for code here then.

Comment: Oh my lord! Dozens of searches never saw that. Also never noticed it there in excel. I will look into how the feature is used and let you know. Thanks. (What did you search?)

Comment: Ok. So yes, the suggestion for the Create Names from Selection is right there and provides a way to do it using the field names. I just had to reconfigure the array. 

The only issue is that some of the names will end up being long. It would be better to have a way to specify the names, and include some conventions (like some fields are linked cell to Active X controls. I'd want to start those with "Lnkd_", but don't want that to be the field label. And again, some of these worksheets have MANY cells. Is there also a VBA solution that can  give more control over the names.?

Comment: I just looked for "create names from cell value", no magic here. • Yes, you can indeed add names with VBA: Have a look at the [Names.Add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.names.add), or research for tutorials. There is no ready to use code so you will have to write your own adjusted to your needs.